# FontForge's SplineSet syntax

Tags: fontforge

Where is the syntax of FontForge's SplineSet (see example below) described?

For simple Splines I can imagine meanings like "m" for move, "l" for line to, "c" for curve etc.

But what are the values after "m", "l", or "c"? What are the arguments of "c"? Is indentation meaningful? etc.

Is there a documentation of the Spline(set)?

```
SplineSet
0 800 m 5
 200 800 l 1
 200 0 l 1
 0 0 l 1
 0 800 l 5
 71.3701171875 163.16015625 114.330681202 164.063746497 183 190 c 24
EndSplineSet
```

Comment: See https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/sfdformat.html#outline-character-data and below. The letters m, l, c are abbreviations for the Postscript commands moveto, lineto, curveto (as mentioned on the linked page), see for example https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf.